# Flutter: How to fix setState() callback argument returned a Future error?

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is to do a simple BitcoinApp. I am trying to get a method that is in the MyHomePageState class to call a method that I have in another class. When I compile and click on the button to give me the bitcoin info of USD I get the error of setState() callback argument returned to Future. Any advice or alternative that you can suggest me? I'm new to Flutter and adjusting.Here is my code:

```
///This piece of code is located in MyHomePageState Class
BitcoinCurrency _bitcoin = BitcoinCurrency();

  void _getUSDBitcoin(){
    setState(() async{
      _bitcoin.usdBitcoin();
    });
  }

///This is the class I have outside of MyHomePageState Class.
class BitcoinCurrency {

  ///Variables we want for the information
  String _disclaimer = "N/A";
  String _time = "N/A";
  String _currencyBitcoin = "N/A";

  ///Getters for our variables
  get disclaimer => _disclaimer;

  get time => _time;

  get currencyBitcoin => _currencyBitcoin;

  ///Methods()

  void usdBitcoin() async{
    var url = Uri.https('api.coindesk.com', '/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
    var response = await http.get(url);

    var httpBody = response.body;

    var decoded = json.decode(httpBody);
    _disclaimer = decoded['disclaimer'];
    _time = decoded['time']['updated'];
    _currencyBitcoin = decoded['bpi']['USD']['rate'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `usdBitcoin` void method to `Future<void>`

```dart
 Future<void>? usdBitcoin() async{
    var url = Uri.https('api.coindesk.com', '/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
    var response = await http.get(url);

    var httpBody = response.body;

    var decoded = json.decode(httpBody);
    _disclaimer = decoded['disclaimer'];
    _time = decoded['time']['updated'];
    _currencyBitcoin = decoded['bpi']['USD']['rate'];
}
```

And call setState like

```dart
 usdBitcoin().then((value) => setState(() {}));
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

`setState` can't be an async function. `usdBitcoin` has to be a `Future` method, so you have to call it before the `setState` starts.

**`usdBitcoin` method:**

```
Future usdBitcoin() async{
    var url = Uri.https('api.coindesk.com', '/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
    var response = await http.get(url);

    var httpBody = response.body;

    var decoded = json.decode(httpBody);
    _disclaimer = decoded['disclaimer'];
    _time = decoded['time']['updated'];
    _currencyBitcoin = decoded['bpi']['USD']['rate'];
}
```

**In `initState`:**

```
usdBitcoin().then(
    (value) => setState(
        () {
          
        },
    ),
)
```